# `cp` fails writing to file / directory while `cat >` and `echo` work fine

Tags: permissions, cp, smb

On a RHEL 7.2 based system I try to copy files to a smb mounted location:

```
cd /target
cp /tmp/foo .
```

This fails with this error message:

```
cp: cannot create regular file ‘./foo’: Operation not permitted
```

I can see that a file with 0 byte size was created.

When I `cat` or `echo Thisisfoobar>foo` this works just fine and the file has the content I want.
But it becomes even more strange, when I do this it works too:

```
cd /target
echo Thisisfoobar>foo
cp /tmp/foo .
```

I don't have the slightest idea why this doesn't work. I already ran a `strace` on both variants (one where `foo` does not exist and one where `foo` exists and is overwritten) and compared the output but saw no relevat differences. The only differences are handles and filesizes like here:

```
stat("./foo", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0700, st_size=12, ...}) = 0
```

We don't use selinux on this machine. Before I run the commands mentioned above I need to do a `sudo adm` (which effectively gives me root-like permissions, this is a limitation imposed by CyberArk) and from this adm shell I do a short `su tu` (or `su - tu`, doesn't make any difference)
Talking of smb: `tu` is member of a group that has permissions to write on the smb mounted device, `tu` is a member of Active Directory.

`ls -laZ /tmp/foo` yields this information:

```
-rwx------ tu user ?                                foo
```

I checked `dmesg`s output while I ran the commands and no entry was appended.

Comment: Do you have selinux running?

Comment: What's the output of the commands 'getenforce' and 'ls -laZ /tmp/foo'?

Comment: @L.Ray `getenforce` tells me it is disabled and `ls` returns `-rw------- tu user ?`. `tu` is the user all of this is running under

Comment: @RamanSailopal No, fortunately selinux isn't involved

Comment: Does dmesg give you any useful information?

Comment: @RamanSailopal Good idea, I forgot about this. Unfortunately there is nothing to be seen